# Logging into a remote website with QT5

Tags: qt, post, qt5

I am attempting to create an application that can login to a website. The specific website is:

http://adfast.biz

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
void MainWindow::http_finish(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    int code = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    if (code >= 300 && code < 400)
    {   //HTTP 3XX codes are redirections
        QUrl redirectTo = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
        reply->manager()->get(QNetworkRequest(redirectTo));
        return;
    }
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QString Msg = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
        if (cdone == 0)
        {//Runs only once, causing a reload of the main page
            ++cdone;
            QUrl URL("http://adfast.biz");
            QNetworkRequest QNR(URL);
            reply->manager()->get(QNR);
            QMessageBox::information(0,"1)" + QString::number(code),Msg);
            return;
        }
        QMessageBox::information(0,"2)" + QString::number(code),Msg);
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0,"Error:",reply->errorString());
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}


void MainWindow::on_Send_clicked()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager* MNAM = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); //Stored within QNetworkReply->manager()
    connect(MNAM,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(http_finish(QNetworkReply*)));
    QUrlQuery postData;
    postData.addQueryItem("email","mail@mail.net");
    postData.addQueryItem("senha","Password");
    postData.addQueryItem("logar","ok");
    QUrl URL(ui->TXT_Input->toPlainText());
    URL.setQuery(postData);
    QNetworkRequest QNR(URL);
    QNR.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    MNAM->post(QNR,URL.toEncoded());
}
```

I am guessing that I either am sending the information the wrong way or that I need to possibly manage cookies? Both responses come back with HTTP status code: 200. The first comes with no source the second comes with the full web-source but is NOT logged in. I am positive that the user-data being sent is correct, but not that it is being sent correctly.

Edit:

I've changed a little, with no luck. First I have added a cookie-jar using:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* MNAM = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); //Stored within QNetworkReply->manager()
QNetworkCookieJar* cJar = new QNetworkCookieJar;
MNAM->setCookieJar(cJar);
connect(MNAM,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(http_finish(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Then, I tested to see if any cookies are being received using the following code at the top of MainWindow::http_finish:

```
QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = reply->manager()->cookieJar()->cookiesForUrl(QUrl("http://adfast.biz/"));
QMessageBox::information(0,"Cookies",QString::number(cookies.count()));
```

I want to add that the post is being sent to: *http://adfast.biz/login* (That is the value of: **ui->TXT_Input->toPlainText()**) But it seems that I can't get this to login at all. And I am not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Little hint: It makes it much easier to read your code, if you format it in a way that no horizontal scrolling is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I did manage to login into this site with testguest@yahoo.com and mypassword12. But I can only offer very quick and dirty code, which explains how. The 'polishing' you must do yourself. :-)

```
QFile f("/tmp/cookie.txt");
f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream s(&f);
while(!s.atEnd()){
    QByteArray c;
    s >> c;
    QList<QNetworkCookie> list = QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(c);
    qDebug() << "eee" << list;
    jar->insertCookie(list.at(0));
 }
    connect(MNAM,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this,SLOT(http_finish(QNetworkReply*)));

QUrlQuery postData;
postData.addQueryItem("email","testguest@yahoo.com");
postData.addQueryItem("senha","mypassword12");
postData.addQueryItem("logar","ok");
//QUrl URL("http://adfast.biz/");
//QUrl URL("http://adfast.biz/anuncios_telexfree");
URL.setQuery(postData);
QNetworkRequest QNR(URL);
QNR.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
MNAM->get(QNR);
```

Above code reads the cookies, which are written in the http_finish slot below into /tmp/cookie.txt.

The first time you run this code, you must uncomment the first URL, the second time, when you have your cookies, the second URL. Ignore that I made your post into a get. I did it just for debugging reasons.

```
void MainWindow::http_finish(QNetworkReply *reply){
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    QList<QNetworkCookie> list =  
        MNAM->cookieJar()->cookiesForUrl(QUrl("http://adfast.biz/"));

    QFile f("/tmp/cookie.txt");
    f.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){
        QDataStream s(&f);
        s << list.at(i).toRawForm();
    }
    f.close();
}
```

The code above writes the cookies from http://adfast.biz/ into /tmp/cookie.txt. Below an example of a cookie, which I received:

```
2-Sep-2013 16:41:39 GMT; domain=adfast.biz; path=/3 16:41:39 GMT; 
domain=adfast.biz; path=/n=adfast.biz; path=/
```

Summary: You must connect to http://adfast.biz/ to get your cookie. When you have it, you must again connect, but this time to http://adfast.biz/anuncios_telexfree.

Comment: Very cool, I will hopefully look at this tomorrow and I'll return with accept.

Comment: Awesome, so, I built a persistent cookie based on this and was able to get it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a [QNetworkCookieJar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkcookiejar.html) to your QNetworkAccessManager for keeping and sending cookies between requests and responses. You can set your cookie jar by using [`QNetworkAccessManager::setCookieJar(QNetworkCookieJar* cookieJar)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setCookieJar). Have a look at the requests being sent using HttpFox in Firefox and you can see if there are any cookies being sent back and forth.

Comment: I tried adding a cookie jar, but it comes back with 0 cookies. I checked with Fiddler and there is cookie-data being used. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect:

```
connect(&MNAM,SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),
        this,SLOT(provideAuthentication(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)));
```

And create a slot:

```
void TrackerClient::provideAuthentication(QNetworkReply *reply, 
                                          QAuthenticator *auth){
    Q_UNUSED(reply);
    auth->setUser(<your username>);
    auth->setPassword(<your password>);
}
```

Comment: I created an http_auth slot and connected MNAM to it as you suggested, but it is never called.

Comment: Too bad. But it was worth a try. Would have surprised me, if QAuthenticator really would have worked with all kinds of authentications.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, second try. The idea to add a cookiejar is correct, but just adding the jar is not enough. I tried the following with another site, which requires login. I did work. For your site I don't have login and password, and since it is not English, it is a little bit too hard for me for a quick help. :-)

How the login procedure works on "my" site.

1. You go to the main url, e.g. www.mysite.something.
2. The site asks you for a cookie. You have none.
3. Your are redirected (status 302 temporary moved) to a 
   page  www.mysite.something/takelogin.php <--- example.
4. You enter your credentials. You already do this in your postdata.addQuery calls.
5. You send your post. If your creds are ok, the site sends you a cookie.

So far so good. What did you wrong? Now that you have the cookie you must **again** go to www.mysite.something. You are not automatically logged in and redirected to the main page of your site. And keep in mind, that cookies in QNetworkCookieJar are not stored on disk. They are only kept in memory. So, if your jar/MNAM is deleted, everything is gone.

You can easily store your received cookies to disk using the `toRawForm()` method of QNetworkCookie. To restore the cookie use the static `QNetworkCooky::parseCookies(const QByteArray &cookieString)` method.

Oh, almost forgot: The main url www.mysite.something did not send any cookies. I had to follow the redirect www.mysite.something/takelogin.php.

Disclaimer: It worked on my site. I don't know, if this is general for all sites, which require a login.

Checked with wrong creds: I was redirected to adfast.biz/login. This seems to be your redirect login page. More I cannot do without real creds.

Comment: testguest@yahoo.com mypassword12 I will look into this, but there is some login information. I just created it.

Comment: Oookay, I managed to login, but my code is very dirty. Best I make a new answer.